# Background transparency, image animation and canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, png

That is more a multidisciplinary issue. I'm making animations with `canvas` and all they need `transparent backgrounds`. As movies can't have `transparent backgrounds` I'm animating `pngs`, and in most of time it's working.

But one of them is a rendered wheel spinning very slow, so it has a lot of frames and hence it will be a lot of images to load and animate. A movie file would be much smaller and much simpler to work with.

I already tried the [jQuery seeThru](https://github.com/m90/jquery-seeThru) library and the result has poor quality.

Somebody have an idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
context.save();
context.globalAlpha=.5;
context.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0);
context.restore();

context.save();
context.globalAlpha=.1;
context.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0);
context.restore();
```